# how to hold xterm during debugging an mpi program?

Tags: gdb, mpi, xterm

I run the debugger via

```
mpirun -n 4 xterm -e gdb -x commands.gdb ./my_mpi_programm
```

where the file "commands.gdb" just contains the commands

```
start
continue
```

The problem is that my 4 xterm immediately close before I get a chance to inspect the error message or do any debugging.

I'm using the latest ubuntu distribution. However, on my friend's old Suse-distribution, xterm is held open.

How can I force the xterms to stay?

EDIT: the "-hold" option doesnt work as well as 
mpirun -n 4 xterm -e "gdb -x commands.gdb ./my_mpi_programm;bash"

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
mpirun -n 4 xterm -e bash -c 'gdb -x commands.gdb ./my_mpi_programm; sleep 60'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `--continuous` flag in mpirun:

```
mpirun -n 4 --continuous xterm -e gdb -x commands.gdb ./my_mpi_programm
```

```
mpirun (Open MPI) 4.1.2

Usage: mpirun [OPTION]...  [PROGRAM]...
Start the given program using Open RTE

   -continuous|--continuous 
                         Job is to run until explicitly terminated
```

Comment: the MPI standard does not specify the `mpirun` command line, so the `--continuous` flag might not be available. Which MPI library are you using?

Comment: mpirun (Open MPI) 4.1.2, Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS